# Read MongoDB _id from JSON file using PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, mongodb

I am reading JSON file using PHP as

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("URL".$fileName),true);
```

It read all data correct **except**

```
"mongoId":"5c9bae50a45f14398668fb03"
```

It is id from MongoDb database written in json file.

but I get this value in PHP as

```
stdClass Object
(
    [timestamp] => 1553706576
    [machineIdentifier] => 10710102
    [processIdentifier] => 13579
    [counter] => 6880003
    [time] => 1553706576000
    [date] => 2019-03-27T17:09:36.000+0000
    [timeSecond] => 1553706576
)
```

Why it converts value in this format and how I can get "5c9bae50a45f14398668fb03" this value from file

file part looks in editor as

```
"someName":[{"mongoId":"5c9bae50a45f14398668fb03",...
```

Comment: Since you are asking within the [tag:mongodb] tag then it's probably safe to presume we already know what an `ObjectId` is. What really is missing from your question is any representation of what the "file" you are reading from actually looks like. I'm kind of betting it's something like `ObjectId("5c9bae50a45f14398668fb03")` and that's actually a mistake and an indicator that whomever created the "files" just dumped output from the `mongo` shell instead of creating a proper export. But if you think it's something else, then please actually show some sample file content for a "record" you want

Comment: It is .json file and I can see value of "mongoId" as "5c9bae50a45f14398668fb03" in editor.  it is  as "mongoId":"5c9bae50a45f14398668fb03"

Comment: I updated it in question

Comment: You already said that in the question. Nothing new here. Actually edit your question to include a "sample record" of all fields **exactly how they appear** within the file you are attempting to read and decode. What you are showing is just a "string" and there is no reason that would not parse. So it's obviously different to what you are claiming. You should just get another field in the data structure with `mongoid` as the key and the "string" as the value. That's not valid for the `_id` value and a real `ObjectId`, but there's still no reason it would not parse.

Comment: In short, you must have other code doing something else which you are not actually showing. `json_decode()` itself does nothing extraordinary, nor is there anything "MongoDB specific" about the JSON you are showing.

Comment: No. I just save decoded data from file_get_contents into variable and when I print it I get mongoId as object with tmestamp and all